# Checking if a string matches dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, search, filtering

If we have a text search field that the user types `11/25/2014` and we have an array of dates:

```
var dates = [ new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24) ];
```

How should we go about checking whether the string entered matches any of the dates?

I assume would first see whether it's actually a valid Date, as the user could have entered `foo` and `new Date('foo')` is an invalid date.

After that is the some of of `includes` like we do with strings for the Javascript Date API?

Comment: I'd recommend Moment.js to remove a lot of pain. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Note that `11` in `new Date(2014, 11, 25)` is December not November [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values)

Comment: @User863 good point about the `11`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the dates using date functions and construct  the desired format and compare it with the input date, look for the index of the formatted date inside the array using `findIndex` :

```js
const input = "11/25/2014";

var dates = [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24)];

const exists = str => dates.findIndex(date => {
  const day = date.getDate();
  const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${monthIndex}/${day}/${year}` === str;
}) > -1 ? true : false;

console.log( exists(input) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need to validate that the input date is actually a valid date, after that you could check if timestamp for input date matches with some of the dates into array, this could could help you

```
const isValidDate = (inputDate, dates) => {
    const now = new Date(inputDate);
    if (isNaN(now)) {
        throw new Error(`${inputDate} is not a valid date`);
        // or return false instead
    }
    // this will return the first date that matches with the input date
    return dates.some(d => d.getTime() === now.getTime());
}
```

Please remember that you actually need to validate the format for the input date, so if the date must keep dd/mm/YYYY you must to validate that the input date keeps that format.

Comment: I like this answer, but the validation step is potentially unecessary. If they put in, say, 'asdf', then the `dates.some()` function would just return false. Which is true - no dates match that input. No need to check if it isNaN or anything

Comment: I assume the code will be more efficient if we check for a valid date first.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on exactly how consistent you expect their input to be. If you're always going to be getting a date that looks like 'DD/MM/YYYY' with no variation, then you're in a good place and can do something quite easy.

```
const userDate = new Date(inputText);
const dates = [ new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 24) ];
const hasMatch = dates.some(d => d.getTime() === userDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Don't know dude - Nice answer - I voted you back up.  Come on people - where's the love!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the milliseconds of dates to compare. Also remember that the month is 0-based so your list is actually December.

```
const input = '12/25/2014';
const test = new Date(input).getTime();
return !isNaN(test) && [new Date(2014, 11, 25), new Date(2014, 11, 26)]
  .map(d => d.getTime())
  .includes(test)
```

One thing to note is depending on the input, browsers are very inconsistent in what formats parse when using `new Date(str)`, so if you want to cover more input formats use something like [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down either - voting you back up.

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-searching-dates?file=index.ts)

```
const input = "11/25/2014";
let result = [];

if (!isNaN(new Date(input).getTime())) {
  result = dates.filter(date=> {
    const day = date.getDate();
    const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const dateString = `${monthIndex}/${day}/${year}`;
    return dateString.includes(input);
  });
}


console.log("The dates that match are: ", result);
console.log("Two dates match: ", result.length == 2);
```